# Build Server using MSBuild cannot resolve reference that is installed in GAC

Tags: .net, jenkins, msbuild

I'm attempting to build a project on a Jenkins Build server that has a reference to Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.

I installed the correct version of this reference in the GAC of the build server. 
Using this command: gacutil /l | find /i "word", I can see that the assembly is installed: Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c.

However the project still fails with the follwing error:
 Could not resolve this reference. Could not locate the assembly "Office, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c". Check to make sure the assembly exists on disk. If this reference is required by your code, you may get compilation errors.

Has anyone encountered this before?

Answer (score -1):

Try re-registering ASP with following command:
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_regiis.exe -iru

And then restart IIS:
iisreset